# Convert php variable into a specified datetime format

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, utc, datetime-format

From server I get this value: **2014-07-02T05:13:45Z**
I stored it into a php variable.

```
$fromserver=$row['today'];
```

So `$fromserver` has value '**2014-07-02T05:13:45Z**' stored in it.

For showing it to users in readable format, I used `strtotime()` & `date()` in php.

Here's my code.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$fs = strtotime($fromserver);
$fromserver_formated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$fs);
```

So, now if I `echo()` `$fromserver_formated`, I get the date in a readable format.

`echo $fromserver_formated;` gives **2014-07-02 05:13:45**.

Now I want to create a new variable `$toserver` using the value of `$fromserver` & `$variable`.

`$variable` is an integer variable containing value 7200.

So to calculate to `$toserver`, I did this.

```
$ts=$fs+$variable;
$toserver=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$ts);
```

And when I `echo $toserver`, I get **2014-07-02 07:13:45**.

And I want to store `$toserver` into my database. But not in '**2014-07-02 07:13:45**' this format but in '**2014-07-02T07:13:45z**' format like `$fromserver`.

What to do next? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's manually added date i think there is not any format to convert .try

```
$fromserver = '2014-07-02 05:13:45';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$fs = strtotime($fromserver);
echo $fromserver_formated = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\z",$fs); //2014-07-02T05:13:45z
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with answers above, where he talk about format for datetime variables already giving not current datetime format or add/sub hours, so I think the right way convert datetime variable string to datetime object and use format as the following:

```
$fromserver = '2014-07-02 05:13:45';
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$mydate = new DateTime($fromserver, $tz);
$formated_date = $mydate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```